# Python scipy chi2_contingency usage

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, statistics

Hello
I'm facing some issues when trying to use the **scipy [chi2_contingency](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html)** function.
To be clear, I want to test the independence of two variable. I have two files which contain the same number of marks (from 0 to 20) and the two variables I mentioned are extracted from those files.
To do this, I proceed like this :

```
data1 = np.array(datalist1)
data2 = np.array(datalist2)
if(len(data1) == len(data2)) :
    bins1 = np.arange(0, 20.001, 20/nbclasses1)
    bins1[len(bins1) - 1] += 1
    data1, bins1 = np.histogram(data1, bins1)
    bins2 = np.arange(0, 20.001, 20/nbclasses2)
    bins2[len(bins2) - 1] += 1
    data2, bins2 = np.histogram(data2, bins2)
    data = [data1, data2]
    chi2, pvalue, dof, a = chi2_contingency(data)
    # valeur du chi2
    self.statdetest_val.config(text = chi2)
    self.valcrit_val.config(text = pvalue)
    if(seuil_alpha > pvalue) :
        #null hypothesis rejected -> dependence 
    else :
        #null hypothesis accepted -> independence
```

So I'm trying to test the independence between the two variables by regrouping values into classes (if I want 20 classes, I will have class 0 to 1, class 1 to 2, ...). For each class, I count the number of values inside and I get an array containing the number of marks per class.
But when I choose a number of classes different for the two variables, I have errors inside **chi2_contingency** function.
I think I don't have understand well how to use this function so maybe someone can explain to me why what I do doesn't work ? And do you think that what I want to do is possible ? 
Thanks by advance !

Comment: *"... I have errors inside chi2_contingency function."*  Please include the *complete* error message (i.e. the full Python traceback) in the question.

Comment: You say *"But when I choose a number of classes different for the two variables, I have errors inside chi2_contingency function."*.  `chi2_contingency` is for the analysis of a [contingency table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table).  It doesn't make sense for a contingency table to have a different number of columns for each row, so it is not clear what you mean when you say "a number of classes different for the two variables".  Can you create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: First, thanks for your response. I'll edit with more information as soon as possible.<br/> But when reading your comment, I feel that I don't really understood how to build this contingency table... Can you explain this to me please ? (if you've understood the context that I've tried to explain)

Comment: I suspect the problem is that you are not using the same bins when you compute the histograms for the two data sets.  Currently, you have `bins1 = np.arange(0, 20.001, 20/nbclasses1)` and `bins2 = np.arange(0, 20.001, 20/nbclasses2)`.  If `nbclasses1` does not equal `nbclasses2`, the bins in the two histograms will not be the same, and you will not have a proper contingency table.

Comment: Ok... I think you're right because after tests, use same bins give a result without error and appearing OK.

Comment: But in this case, if I have two data sets like A = [0,3,4,7,9,11,12.5,15,17,19,20] and B = [5,7,8,10,12,13.5,14,16,16,17,19]          . They contain the same number of marks (11). I want to build the contingency table and for each variable I have :         For A : [0;5[ -> 3 marks , [5,10[ -> 2 marks , [10,15[ -> 2marks , [15,20] -> 4 marks       and for B : [0,4[ -> 0 marks , [4,8[ -> 2 marks , [8,12[ -> 2 marks , [12,16[ -> 3 marks , [16,20] -> 4 marks          . So different bins for the two variable, is it possible to build a contingency table with those data ?

Comment: And thank you for your time !

Comment: Using different bins seems to go against the usual assumptions of a contingency table, but maybe there is a way to interpret your data such that it makes sense.  Questions about defining and interpreting a contingency table are more appropriately asked on http://stats.stackexchange.com/.   Once you have have that straightened out, you can use stackoverflow for questions about the implementation.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help, I'll try to get more information about contingency tables !